# how to add option None to select using material UI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm working on material ui react storybook. I have mapped select options because i dont wnat to hardcode select options. How do i add None to this like Material Ui select component. When i choose None, nothing should be selected same like material ui react select component. Please help.Thanks

[image]

```
     import React from "react";
        import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
        import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
        import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
        import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
        import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
        
     import React from "react";
    import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
    import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
    
    const age = ["None",Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"];
    export const SelectBa = ({}) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
    
      const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
        const {
          target: { value }
        } = event;
        setPersonName(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }} size={size}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">{selectname.map((label) => { label })}</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
            >
              {age.map((age) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={age}
                  value={age}
                  style={getStyles(age, personName, theme)}
                >
                  {age}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SelectBa;


stories.js

export const Selectde = SelectBa.bind({});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Material UI doc, you can see these menu items to check the source code.

[image]

In the source code, you will see the empty value option.

[image]

Comment: @i want to map with other select options as i did in above code. But if i add it in same way None is behaving as one of the options.

Comment: Add the none option before the loop
This way you guarantee that the none option will appear on top of the loop

Comment: after adding it before the loop .If i select the None from options it is behaving as one of the options, whereas it shouldn't get selected & select should be empty

Comment: Can you provide the code sample where it is happening?